# PHP: почему переменная в рекурсии становится undefined

Tags: php, рекурсия

прошу объяснить почему $resArray оказывается undefined при исполнении рекурсии

```
$test = [1,2,[[3,[4,5],6],7,8],9,0];
function reduceArrDimensions($array) {
    isset($resArray) ?: $resArray = [];
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $nested) {
            $returnArr = reduceArrDimensions($nested);
        }
    } else {
        $resArray[] = $array;
    }
}
reduceArrDimensions($test);
```

Comment: ну всё правильно. А почему она должна быть не undefined? она определена внутри функции со своей областью видимости, к тому же не передаётся никуда и не возвращается. И зачем свой велосипед городить когда есть готовая array_reduce функция?

Comment: @DmitriiSedov
array_reduce, как понял, не о том. задача уменьшить размерность массива, а не количество значений

Comment: array_reduce сводит к единому значению, всё верно. Но! Единое значение это не обязательно число, строка, это может и какой-нибудь массив, класс, и т.д. К чему вы тут и сводите собственно. Уменьшить ли вы массив хотите или увеличить это не важно.

Comment: Добавил ответ ниже!

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov, буду осознавать. спасибо

Comment: Отмечайте ответ ниже как верный (поставить галочку), если он Вам помог, чтобы он индексировался и другие пользователи столкнувшись с похожей проблемой смогли найти ответ быстрее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с исправленной ошибкой и с использованием `array_reduce`

```
$test = [1,2,[[3,[4,5],6],7,8],9,0];
function reduceArrDimensions($carry, $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        $carry = array_reduce($item, 'reduceArrDimensions', $carry);
    }
    else $carry[] = $item;
    return $carry;
}

$newArr = array_reduce($test, 'reduceArrDimensions', []);
var_dump($newArr);
```